# Ordering an Active Record Query by a Column in Another Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to order my active record query by a specific table column but with the standard `Query.order(:id)` format rails thinks the column is in a different table.

This is my active record query:

`@course = Course.select('*').joins(:course_metadata, :courseContent).where(course_id: params[:id]).order(:content_order)`

Here are my models:

```
    class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_one :course_metadata
        has_many :xrefCourseContent, foreign_key: 'course_id'
        has_many :courseContent, through: :xrefCourseContent, foreign_key: 'course_guid'
    end


    class CourseMetadata < ActiveRecord::Base
        self.table_name = 'course_metadata'
        belongs_to :course
    end


    class CourseContent < ActiveRecord::Base
        self.table_name = 'courseContent'
        has_many :xrefCourseContent, foreign_key: 'content_id', primary_key: 'content_id'
        has_many :course, through: :xrefCourseContent, foreign_key: 'content_id', 
    end


    class XrefCourseContent < ActiveRecord::Base
        self.table_name = 'xrefCourseContent'
        belongs_to :course, primary_key: 'course_id', foreign_key: 'course_guid'
        belongs_to :courseContent, primary_key: 'content_id', foreign_key: 'content_guid'
    end
```

The query connects courses to course content through the xref table.

```
SELECT * FROM [courses] 
INNER JOIN [course_metadata] ON [course_metadata].[course_id] = [courses].[course_id] 
INNER JOIN [xrefCourseContent] ON [xrefCourseContent].[course_id] = [courses].[course_id] 
INNER JOIN [courseContent] ON [courseContent].[content_id] = [xrefCourseContent].[content_id] 
WHERE [courses].[course_id] = @0 
ORDER BY [courses].[content_order]
```

This is the sql query that shows up in the error message and as you can see, it thinks the `content_order` column is in the `courses` table when in fact it is in the `xrefCourseContent` table.

I'm new to rails and am still trying to wrap my mind around the whole Active Record system so forgive me if some of the code in my models is redundant or unnecessary, but feel free to point out anything that could be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
@course = Course.select('*').joins(:course_metadata, :courseContent)
 .where(course_id: params[:id])
 .order("xrefCourseContents.content_order")
```

You need to specify the table from which you will find the `content_order` column.